# Describing circles as a indexed family of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following task:

"Describe the following as an indexed family of sets. Here $\Pi$ denotes the coordinatized xy-plane: The family of all circles in $\Pi$ of radius 1."

the general equation would be of the form:
$$ (x-a)^2 + (y -b)^2 = 1$$

or one of the other equivalent equations. I am unsure  how one is able to determine the index given that  the centre would be depend on two variables

Comment: You say that each circle is picked out (indexed) by a pair of (real) numbers.  Can you think of a set that contains pairs of real numbers?

Comment: @EricTowers $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: There's also $\mathbb{\Pi}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Something like this, $\{C_{(a,b)}\}_{(a,b) \in \Pi}$?

Comment: @mvw Why the midpoint over the centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like somethin like this:

$$
\mathcal{A} = \{ A_u \,\left|\, u \in \Pi \right. \} \quad 
\mbox{where} \quad 
A_u = \left\{ v \in \Pi \left| \, ||v - u|| = 1 \right. \right\}
$$

Comment: So my notation above is wrong?

Comment: Not really. I just used the norm of a vector as shorthand, that is equal to your circle equation. The missing bit is the family of sets $\mathcal A$ indexed by elements from $\Pi$. And I didn't care about the points / vectors beeing 2D, as fas as thery are distinguishable elements of the index set.

Comment: I mean this : $\{C_{(a,b)}\}_{(a,b) \in \Pi}$

Comment: Ah sorry, that looked too much like the set of continous functions over the open interval $(a,b)$ for my taste, but is ok, if you specified $C_{(a,b)}$

Answer (score 1):

If $\Pi$ is a set of ordered pair numbers (reals or not) representing the coordinates on a plane, the family of its circles of radius $r$ can be expressed as a category ($r-circles$) by the following proposition:

$ \forall (A_u \in A \mid u \in \Pi) \rightarrow A_u = \{ p \in \Pi \bigg| ((p_1-u_1)^2 + (p_2-u_2)^2) = r  \}  $